# actual value is blank error for verifyText in Selenium

Tags: selenium

I am trying out Selenium IDE for my testing.  I have created a test case that will edit an input field in a form and then I wanted to check if the value was actually changed.  I tried using both AssertText and VerifyText and both are failing with the message [error] Actual value '' did not match 'M'.  The log have the following entries:

```
[info] script is: window.location.hash='/mainmasterdata/customer'
[info] Executing: |click | //input[@value='View'] | |
[info] Executing: |waitForElementPresent | css=fieldset.ng-binding | |
[info] Executing: |click | //a[contains(text(),'Automated')] | |
[info] Executing: |waitForElementPresent | id=gender | |
[info] Executing: |verifyText | css=#gender | M |
[error] Actual value '' did not match 'M'
[info] Test case failed
```

Here's the element in the html file:

```
    <p>Gender : <input name="gender"
                          type="text" 
                          ng-model="masterData.customerInformation.gender"
                          id="gender"
                          </input>
    </p>
```

When I try to inspect the element in firefox, here's what I can see:

```
<p>
Gender :
<input id="gender" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty" name="gender" ng-model="masterData.customerInformation.gender" <="" input="" type="text">
</p>
```

I am not really sure why there is an 'input = ""' entry when I inspect the element.

Comment: Update: I was able to identify the problem with the 'input=""' appearing which was due to a missing '>' in the input.  However, even after correcting this, the same problem still exists in Selenium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is happening because you are trying to verifyText of an `<input>` box.  Input's don't have "text" per-se.  `verifyText` will inspect the `innerText` of an element.

Since the "text" of an input field is held within a value;

What you want, is `verifyValue`